# I need to get the 3 and 4 digit numbers out of a list of multiple numbers

Tags: python, string, list, integer

So I have been given lst = [1001, 21, 1, 404, 200, 12010], and when I run the program I need to print out only the 3 and 4 digits : [1001, 400, 200].

```
>>> lst = [1001, 21, 1, 404, 200, 12010, 2002]
>>> str_lst = str(lst)

>>> new_lst = [len(number) for number in str_lst]
>>> print(new_lst)
```

and the result of this code is [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

I've tried this after your comment :

```
new_lst = [len(str(number)) for number in lst]

print(new_lst)

for number in new_lst == 3 and number in new_lst == 4: 

   final_result.append(number)

print(final_result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `str_lst = str(lst)`, it converts this `[1001, 21, 1, 404, 200, 12010, 2002]` to one whole string. Thus when you'll print your `str_list` you'll get an output like this - `'[1001, 21, 1, 404, 200, 12010, 2002]'`, which is one string literal.

```
print(str_lst[0])
```

> > [

```
print(str_lst[1])
```

> > 1

What you need is to convert every individual element of your original list to string. Which can be achieved like:

```
new_lst = [len(str(number)) for number in lst]
```

The output of the above code will be:

```
print(new_lst)
```

> > [4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 5, 4]

This way you can get a list whose elements are the length of the elements of the original list.

Just a suggestion:
While debugging small problems, try printing out values after every operation. This why you can compare the output with your expectations. Not only this will help you get a solution, you'll also learn Python in much more depth.

Edited after comments:

```
final_result = []
for count, i in enumerate(new_lst):
  if i >= 3:
    final_result.append(lst[count])

print(final_result)
```

Comment: Alright, I saw what I was doing wrong but now I got to print out the list with only the 3 and 4 digit numbers out of all that , and I'm kinda stuck here too

Comment: You could edit your question and show what you tried and we can help you out.

Comment: I did but oh my why does it look like one continuous text and not like a code because I wrote it as if it was code

Comment: Your syntax `for number in new_lst == 3 and number in new_lst == 4:` is wrong. Try reading about loops and conditionals in python. I'll edit the answer to show you to final result.

Comment: What I have shown in the answer is a long method. You can easily simplify the answer much and write a much better version of it. My solution works but I'd suggest you try to find a more optimal solution. It'll be a good practice for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am reading and getting the code through Thonny to fully understand and learn what is going on exactly. Thanks!

Comment: If this answered all your questions, you can think of up-voting it!